# Перевести консольное приложение (игра "Жизнь" на C#) в графическое

Tags: c#, gui, f#, консоль, bitmap

Дело в том, что я - человек, бесконечно далекий от графических приложений, интерфейсов, GUI и прочего в том же роде. Программирую я в Notepad++, компилирую в командной строке. Visual Studio даже не установлена на компьютере. Исходя из этого, как проще мне сделать?

[Вот что у меня есть](http://codepad.org/TzNtDtUE)

[А вот что я хочу сделать](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.ru/2010/02/john-conways-game-of-life-in-32-lines.html)

С удовольствием приму любые советы, начиная с алгоритма и вплоть до оформления исходников. Однако в первую очередь интересует вопрос создания графических приложений без Visual Studio, которая все за разработчика делает, разве что сопли ему не вытирает. :)

Comment: Без комментариев довольно сложно понять, что именно выполняет код.

Comment: Без VS в Notepad++ можно создавать графические приложения, и не сложно, разве что больше времени уходит выравнивание положения элементов. С моей стороны была попытка сделать отображение КА путем перерисовки Bitmap попиксельно, при небольшом мире в виде тора получается терпимо.

Comment: @Valeriy Karchov: Вы имеете в виду SetPixel? Насколько я знаю, это медленно. Хотелось бы сделать как можно ближе к тому коду, который по второй ссылке в моем вопросе. Неужели на C# это сложнее, чем на F#?

Comment: @VadimTukaev, я бы сказал, что это очень медленно :)

Comment: _"А вот что я хочу сделать"_ -- по этой ссылке не консольное приложение. там просто фон черный. в коде обратите внимание на System.Windows.Media.Imaging и BitmapSource.Create -- это WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кому-то это все еще интересно, то я нашел решение - http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Image_noise#C.23

Answer (score 2):

Вторая строчка из приведённой вами ссылки

```
including real-time visualization using Windows Presentation Foundation
```

гласит, что ваша программа "образец" использует WPF... Т.е. уже как минимум очевидно, что автор той программы использовал студию... и контрол Image:

```
let image = Controls.Image(Stretch=Media.Stretch.Uniform)
```

Проекты типа WPF в отличие от классических WinForm для отрисовки графики используют DirectX. Если, как вы мне ответили, вы не планируете использовать то, что даёт студия, и при этом хотите такой же скорости (а не как у SetPixel), то вам нужно копать в сторону использования графических пакетов DirectX: скачиваем SDK, находим мануалы и вперёд.

Вариант второй, взять сгенерированную студией папку WPF проекта с реализованным рисованием. Разобраться, как вашим способом выводить на экран пустую форму (где вы будите рисовать), и разобраться с подключением и использованием тех же библиотек для рисования, что используются в WPF.

Comment: Тогда, пожалуй, буду делать через SetPixel... Или, как вариант, создавать массив байт и потом его отображать на Bitmap. Вот похожая задача, только там картинка читается как массив байт, а мне надо будет записывать - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38619/Finding-a-Bitmap-contained-inside-another-Bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Пилите битмап по размеру поля, закрашиваете "живые" клетки, выводите. Про вывод можно почитать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378642/c-pixels-in-console-window).

Comment: Там WinApi и SetPixel. Я хотел что-то более дотнетоориентированное.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример:
http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-life-conways-game-of-life--gamedev-558
Может, подойдет

Comment: Там вообще все через XNA. Для моих задач это явно оверинжиниринг.